# android radio group layout

Tags: android, layout, radio-group

I have a radio group that consists of 4 radio buttons and I'm trying to align them in 2 rows with 2 buttons in each row. How should I go about nesting layouts so that I get the desired result? I have tried putting 2 LinearLayout views with horizontal alignment inside the radio group but that didn't work. Is a table my only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a layout to a radio group.  You are probably best handling the the selection criteria using your own code.

EDIT:

quick thought... not sure on what you are trying to achieve you could split the radiogroup into two.  but since radiogroup is based on a LinearLayout i don't think it would help much.

Comment: I opted for your suggestion by putting the buttons inside a TableLayout and handling the radio group event boilerplate myself.